# Unseen BTC transaction in a blockchain Wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, lost-transactions

if a BTC transaction is made in to a blockchain wallet address and it is not seen in it activities but appears in the blockchain explorer that the transaction has been made  What will I do
266fddc5f0ca7a8afb89931ea71ee0cb21b6b6f84f3061e2428f656fcf25b9f9

Comment: Hi Besong, do I understand correctly that you are using a blockchain.com wallet and the transaction appears on the block explorer but not on the wallet? Have you confirmed that the address on the blockexplorer matches the one in your wallet?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed that the address matches. I bought the BTC from switchere and send to a friend using blockchain wallet.This is the wallet 1JkRcgMn8peDXsJXU4j7sQytP3RCcTk7Za and this is the order 266fddc5f0ca7a8afb89931ea71ee0cb21b6b6f84f3061e2428f656fcf25b9f9

Comment: I need some to verify for me if the transaction was safely deposited in that wallet and why it did not appear in the wallet activity